# Can't name a class function 'restart'

Tags: python, class

I was coding in python and suddenly I got an error saying 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable'. I checked the code and apparently there was a class function called 'restart' that was causing the error(but there was nothing wrong with the class function as it had not been execute yet). But when I renamed that class function to something else, my code worked fine. Could someone please explain on why this happens?
This is my code:

```
class score_screen():
    def restart():
        self.final_score = (25*self.points)-self.loss
        self.restart = True

thing = score_screen()
thing.restart()
```

Comment: That error almost always happens because you've used the name of a built-in function as a variable, e.g. `int = 3` or `print = 5`

Comment: There's nothing special about the method name `restart`. The problem is almost certainly something else.

Comment: The problem is `self.restart = True`. After you do that, `restart` is no longer a function, it's the value `True`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code a bit more so that it's easier to understand

Comment: Don't use the same name `restart` for a method and variable.

Comment: Ok thanks for telling me. I fixed the code and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each object in Python + its class, has a single namespace for both attributes and methods.

When you do `self.restart = True` in your code, you are shadowing the method "restart" itself: you have to use ".restart" either for the method name *or*, exclusively, for the attribute name, not both.

When you renamed the method, and kept the attribute name, things worked just like they should:

```
class score_screen():
    def restart():
        self.final_score = (25*self.points)-self.loss
        self.restart = True

thing = score_screen()
thing.restart()
```

Above is your code: `.restart()` will work the first time it is called for each instance - and the code in the method body itself will create an instance attribute, named `restart` which will have priority over the method name, the next time you write `instance.restart`. When you try to call it `instance.restart()` Python will try to call `True` :in Python booleans are a subclass of `int`s - that is the reason you get an "Int object is not callable" error.

Comment: Of course, this only works if the method is defined with the required parameter `self`: `def restart(self):`.